# Displaying a thumbnail of a JFreeChart on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, thumbnails, jfreechart

I'm currently working with time-series data and I'm using JFreeCharts XYLineChart to display my data. For my user interface I want to create click-able thumbnails of these charts (which then show the real big Chart).

I tried this method to create a thumbnail of the chart, but I don't know how I can use this BufferedImage to display the thumbnail.

```
XYSeriesCollection coll = new XYSeriesCollection();
coll.addSeries(rw.getT1().getCurMktCapSeries());
coll.addSeries(rw.getT2().getCurMktCapSeries());            
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(rw.getT1().getName() + " - " + rw.getT2().getName(),
                                            "Position",
                                            "Course",
                                            coll,
                                            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                                            true,
                                            true,
                                            false);
    
BufferedImage bi = chart.createBufferedImage(1000, 1000, 100, 100, null);
```

I tried searching online, but the only thing I found was the method above to create a thumbnail, not how to display it.

So my question are:

- Is this the right way to create a thumbnail?
- How can I display this thumbnail on my GUI?

## Solution

I just created my own custom JPanel

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel
```

and then I added the following paintComponent method to draw the thumbnail

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    //Create Image
    BufferedImage bi = this.createBufferedImage(this.rw);
    //Draw Background
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setColor(this.backgroundColor);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    //Draw Image
    g2d.drawImage(bi.getScaledInstance(this.getWidth()-10, this.getHeight()-10, 0), 5, 5, this.backgroundColor, null);
}
```

To create the BufferedImage I used the following method

```
private BufferedImage createBufferedImage(ResultWrapper rw2) {
    //Create JFreeChart
    XYSeriesCollection coll = new XYSeriesCollection();
    coll.addSeries(rw.getT1().getCurMktCapSeries());
    coll.addSeries(rw.getT2().getCurMktCapSeries());            
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(null, null, null, coll, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
    
    //Hide Axis
    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    plot.getRangeAxis().setVisible(false);
    plot.getDomainAxis().setVisible(false);
    
    return chart.createBufferedImage(500, 500, 100, 100, null);
}
```

With that I got exactly what I wanted, little thumbnails of a JFreeChart. To make it clickable, just add a MouseListener.

Thanks @MadProgrammer for using a custom component and the paintComponent method

Comment: *"Is this the right way to create a thumbnail?"*  Does it look right?  A picture paints a thousand words, so a thumbnail paints at least a paragraph.  Please also consider asking one question per question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ontop of AndrewThompon's suggestions, you could provide a custom Component that has the ability to paint the chart.

Take a look at

- [Performing Custom Painting in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Java Graphcs2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

This is by far more involved then has already been suggested, but does provide you with the greatest of flexibility

Comment: Thank you,

I just created my own custom JPanel and drew the BufferedImage in the paintCompoment method.
Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I display this thumbnail on my GUI?

There are a number of ways, but given the use-case, you might look at using it as the icon of a `JButton`/`JRadioButton` or the tab of a `JTabbedPane`, or in a `JList` or `JComboBox`.

Look over [A Visual Guide to Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html) for a quick tour of the possibilities.

Comment: @Mad I'm glad you added a ;) or I might have had to rouse on you for suggesting a component that is by default not focusable when there are so many other possibilities that are not only focusable, but also have direct hooks to event detection.  I was going to add `JTree` to the original list, but thought that was stretching the bounds of 'fit the use case', but a `JLabel`?  Huck.. ptui..  ;)

Comment: the question is a little fuage in that direction. :p JLabel was the first thing that came to mind, but fair point about focusable